# Method Shadowing Using NSubstitute in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I have a Public method to test which Calls a public Child-Method:

The Child Method has an Optional parameter :

```
public class ChildClass : IChildClass
{
        public bool MyChildMethod(string param1, string param2, string param3 = null)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

The Parent Methods invokes the child like:

```
_childClassInstance.MyChildMethod("param1","param2")
```

When I run my UnitTestCase, I want to substitute it like:

```
_childClassInstance.MyChildMethod("param1","param2","param3")
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Why would you want to substitute method behaviour to unexpected  behaviour? If the parent class won't call the method in this way, the substitute is useless....

Comment: The optional parameter here is actually a DbSession(dependency injection) which I need to Rollback the DB-changes after my test-case has executed.

Comment: So why don't you solve this issue with `Teardown`?(Test class has a reference to `_childClassInstance`, then in `Teardown` execute the rollback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nsubstitute you can shadow the public-method call by the following way :

```
mockObj.When(x => mockObj.MyChildMethod(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>(), null)).Do(MyMethod)

private void MyMethod(CallInfo callInfo)
        {
            mockObj.MyChildMethod((string)callInfo.Args()[0],(string)callInfo.Args()[1], "param3");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is there is no way to mock the behavior of a private method and generally you don't want to concern yourself with private methods in unit testing since they are considered an "implementation detail".

If this method were public however, using the Moq framework you could do the following.

```
Mock<MyChildClass> mockChildClass = new Mock<MyChildClass>();
mockChildClass.Setup(x => x.MyChildMethod("param1", "param2", "param3"));
```